# DB connections: with closing() vs __del__

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Using SQLAlchemy to connect to MySQL and I've gotten tired of writing things like this:

```
with closing(engine) as connection:
    do_sql_stuff(connection)
```

This pattern is repeated throughout many areas of my code and it seems with the availability of `__del__` this is not necessary.  Why not just implement a class to wrap the connection creation and closing:

```
class MyConnectionManager(object):
    def __init__(self, db_uri):
        self.__db_engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(db_uri)
        self.__db_conn = self.__db_engine.connect()

    def __del__(self):
        self.__db_conn.close()
```

Is this simply two different styles/preferences, or are there more important reasons that using `with closing()` is a better way to go that using `__del__` (or vice versa)?

Comment: Ask yourself: why did they add `with` when they already had `del`? Then, look at [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__del__) and see if there is any hint there, such as a giant grey box with the word "Note" in it in boldface, or better yet, a giant *red* (OK, pink) box with the word "Warning" in it in boldface.

Comment: @kindall - thanks, I've read the docs and wanted to get more info from the community on what is being done in practice.

Comment: @kindall - and corollary to your first point, if `__del__` is so broken, why didn't they remove it?

Comment: `__del__` isn't broken, but it's a very last resort and does not do some things some mis-informed people *expect* it to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no guarantee about when `__del__` is actually called (or if it is called at all in the case of circular references).  `with closing(...) as ...:` guarantees that the cleanup code is called whenever you exit the `with` clause.

Comment: thanks, I think I  might be able to simplify my code by using `close_with_result` via SQLAlchemy.  Thoughts?  http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.base.ResultProxy

Comment: I don't actually use SQLAlchemy -- so most of that stuff has no real meaning to me -- I guess that is to say that I don't have any thoughts on the matter other than using the context manager is probably the way the API is designed to be used (even if you find it slightly annoying).